# Field 'sno' expected a number but got ''

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am creating a website where anyone can ask questions and on that question, anyone can give answer, but when i code to get answer from user, when user submit his answers they found Error that is ValueError:Field 'sno' expected a number but got ''.

Here is my codes:

models.py

```
# This code handle user posts
class QueryPost(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Query_post = models.TextField()
    Query_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "Query_image", blank=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + '  '   + str(self.timeStamp.date())

#This code for get user answers 
class QueryAns(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    Query_ans = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ans_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = "Query_ans_image", blank=True)
    queryPost = models.ForeignKey(QueryPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + '  '   + str(self.timeStamp.date())
```

views.py

```
def queryPost(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        user_ = request.user
        Query_post_ = request.POST.get('Query_post','')
        Query_image_ = request.POST.get('Query_image','')
        
        #condition 
        if len(Query_post_) == 0:
            messages.error(request, "somting went wrong")
            return redirect('Home')  
        #creat post
       
        Query_obj = QueryPost(user=user_ , Query_post=Query_post_, Query_image=Query_image_)
        Query_obj.save()
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Query post")

        return redirect('/Query')
    else:
        messages.error(request, "somting went wrong")
        return HttpResponse('404-not found')

def queryAns(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Query_ans_ = request.POST.get("Query_ans")
        user = request.user
        queryPostSno = request.POST.get("queryPostSno")
        queryPost = QueryPost.objects.get(sno=queryPostSno)
        ans_image_ = request.POST.get("ans_image")

        answer = QueryAns(user=user, Query_ans=Query_ans_, ans_image= ans_image_, queryPost=queryPost)
        answer.save()
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Answer post")

        return redirect("/Query")
    else:
        messages.error(request, "somting went wrong")
        return HttpResponse('404-not found')
```

urls.py

```
    path('Query/', views.Query, name='Query'),
    path('queryPost', views.queryPost, name='queryPost'),
    path('queryAns', views.queryAns, name='queryAns'),
    path('Query/<str:slug>', views.querySlug, name='querySlug'),
```

here is HTML file code

```
<form action='/queryAns' method="POST" , enctype="multipart/form_data">
 {% csrf_token %}
<input type="text" id="Query_ans" name="Query_ans">
 <input type="hidden" name="queryPostSno" value="{{queryPost.sno}}">
<button type="submit" class=" btn btn-outline-primary  btn-block ">Submit</button>
</form>
```

please find the error.

Comment: You should use Django forms for handling user input, they encapsulate error handling and field validation

Comment: Thanks man , but i'm beginning in django , can you you please explain your answer how can i apply it .